# Aller dans un bar / Aller à un bar

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Dans un exercice de français, une phrase à trous apparaît:

> Je ___ un bar en face de chez moi. Viens avec moi.

Le but est d'exprimer cette phrase en anglais:

> I'm going to a bar opposite my building. Come with me.

[image: Aller dans un bar]

`vais à` est refusé, la solution attendue est `vais dans`.

L'exercice est-il correct ?

Comment: Pour des éléments de réponse, une question similaire a été posée ailleurs : http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic34532-aller-a-ou-aller-dans.html La conclusion semble être que les deux constructions sont justes mais aucune règle n'est donnée sur le choix de « dans » ou « à ». Voir mon commentaire sur [la réponse de Kimi](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14735/7224) pour des exemples avec « aller à ». « Aller dans » semble effectivement être le cas d'exception.

Answer (score 2):

*Aller à un bar n'est pas correct*, si l'on considère que le café ou la brasserie dans laquelle on se rend est un *bar*.

*Aller au bar* est correct quand on est dans un café, un bar, une brasserie et qu'on se rend au comptoir.

*Aller au NomDuBar*  est correct, aller à l'église (le lieu où le culte est pratiqué, non le bâtiment) ou cinéma (pour être devant un écran) aussi, car il ne s'agit pas d'une place ou d'un lieu, mais d'une institution, d'une marque, d'un nom propre.

---

- 1°) *Aller à* indique se déplacer dans une direction (je vais à Paris), se rendre dans un lieu, ou près d'un lieu (je vais à la pèche, donc près de la rivière), où dans un lieu symbolique (Si je suis bien sage j'irai au Ciel !)
- 2°) *Aller dans* indique que l'on va  à l'intérieur d'un espace (Si je pouvais, j'irais dans l'espace).

Comment: Ce raisonnement semble pertinent mais je ne trouve pas comment faire rentrer l'exemple « aller à la gare » dans ce cadre. Cela est-il considéré comme une institution en raison du service de transport pour lequel on s'y rend le plus souvent ? Ou ignore-t-on qu'il s'agit d'un bâtiment (pour une gare ferroviaire) parce que les quais sont généralement en extérieur ?

Comment: @Chop Le sens premier de gare : "Emplacement situé sur une voie de chemin de fer pour le croisement des trains". Ensuite on a posé dessus de beaux bâtiments et toute une société. *Je vais à la gare* signifie *je vais sur les quais* (qui ne sont pas *dans* la gare, mais sous un espace couvert ouvert à tous les vents et se prolongent au-delà), là où un train s'arrête pendant que les autres peuvent circuler. Il faudrait dire : "Je vais *dans* la gare de Lyon acheter mes billets", en effet, la billetterie est dans le bâtiment, même si familièrement on dit "Je vais à la gare de Lyon acheter..."

Comment: L'explication ne tient pas debout : on va à la boulangerie, au musée (ou dans un musée), au parc (mais dans la forêt), à la piscine (pour aller dans l'eau)... On va pourtant bien à l'intérieur de la boulangerie, du musée, de la piscine... (Pour le parc, on peut dire qu'on est dessus et pas vraiment dedans, c'est peut-être ce qui explique la différence avec la forêt). On va au restaurant ou dans un restaurant, ça n'a pas tout à fait le même sens.

Comment: @Gilles  **1°)**  *boulangerie* (1-*Fabrication* et commerce du pain, 2-boutique du boulanger), *piscine* (1 *Bassin* pour les rites purificatoires ; Petite cuve destinée à recevoir l'eau des baptêmes, 2 Grand bassin de natation et ensemble des installations qui l'entourent), *parc* (I - 1 *Clôture*.. 2 *enclos*.. 3 place réservée .. II 1 Grande étendue boisée et clôturée.. pour la chasse…  2 Étendue de terrain... autour d'un château ... 3 *Espace aménagé en plein air pour le public*), *musée* (1 *Centre d'études scientifiques* créé par les Ptolémées à Alexandrie, 2 Cabinet d'homme de ...

Comment: lettres … 2 Établissement…) je vais là où se fabrique le pain (dans la boulangerie X), Comme pour la gare où je vais sur les quais à l'extérieur des bâtiments, je vais *au bord* du bassin (autrefois très souvent en plein air) puis, éventuellement *dans l'eau* de ce bassin, je nage *dans le bassin* et pas *dans la piscine* si c'est le bâtiment, je ne vais pas dans la clôture du parc, mais sur une surface clôturée. Voilà pour le 1°)  et **le 2°)** : Forêt « en dehors (foris de l'enclos) » ou « forêt) du tribunal royal » Vaste étendue de terrain peuplée principalement d'arbres--Source Le Robert).

Comment: Le sens usuel est un dérivé du sens originel, la gare, la boulangerie, la piscine, le parc sont des bâtiments ou des lieux perçus dans leur utilité usuelle, et non dans leur fonction primordiale : un des sens d'aller *aller à* correspond à *se diriger vers*, ici on se dirige vers le sens primordial, même si on se retrouve *dans* (en pensant au sens usuel). Je n'ai pas encore trouvé d'exemple où le cas 1°) ne fonctionne pas,  mais je suis prêt à améliorer ma réponse. J'ai l'impression que c'est  la sémantique ou l'étymologie qui dirige le choix de l'usage entre *aller à* et *aller dans*.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux formules ne signifient pas tout à fait la même chose mais la différence ne se manifeste pas dans toutes les circonstances de façon évidente.

La construction avec *à* n'impose pas que le complément ait un intérieur, il suffit que le point d'arrivée soit proche :

> Je vais à la fenêtre (‘I'm going to the window’)
>
> ?Je vais dans la fenêtre.

Si on se donne rendez-vous *à la gare*, ça peut être devant mais pas si on se donne rendez-vous *dans la gare*.

Pour ce qui est d'aller *à/dans* un bar, il y a encore d'autres contrastes. La première chose concerne la non-spécificité qui est en général associé avec l'article indéfini (*un/une*). Dans le cas, des bars, boulangeries et autres commerces de proximité, on utilise plutôt l'article défini avec *à* même dans les cas où on n'a pas de commerce précis en tête :

> Il est sorti, il est allé à la boulangerie.
>
> #Il est sorti, il est allé à une boulangerie.

Dans le deuxième cas, on pourrait imaginer qu'il m'a dit où il allait, je sais que c'est une boulangerie mais je ne me souviens pas des détails.

Pour *dans*, c'est l'usage intuitif défini/indéfini qui prévaut.

> Je vais dans un bar en face de mon immeuble.

Il peut y avoir des bars en face et je vais aller dans l'un d'entre eux.
Pour garder la non-spécificité avec *à*, on pourrait aussi dire :

> Je vais à un des bars en face de mon immeuble.

Mais ça ne reflèterait pas la simplicité de la phrase en anglais.

Answer (score -1):

L'exercice est tout à fait correct, "aller à un bar" ne se dit pas en français.

Je ne connais pas la règle exacte mais en général quand cela concerne un bâtiment, on dit "dans un".
Je vais dans un bâtiment. (Et non je vais à un bâtiment).

Voilà voilà !

Comment: Oui, et non. « Aller à un bar » me semble faux, mais « aller au bar » ne me choque pas. De même, lorsque l'on prend le train, on parle généralement d'« aller **à** la gare » (ou pour un autre exemple masculin incontestable, on va souvent **au** cinéma). Je pense qu'il faut creuser un peu plus les règles autour de cette question. J'ai l'impression que à + article indéfini est faux, mais pas forcément à + article défini.

Comment: @Chop: "*à + article indéfini est faux*" <- D'une manière générale, ou dans un contexte particulier ? Par exemple "je vais à un concert" est correct, non ?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Exact. Je songeais au cas des bâtiments, mais je serais heureux si nous arrivions à formuler une règle générale sur l'usage de à et dans après aller. Je chercherai encore un peu ce soir. Merci pour l'exemple.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, en fait tu as répondu toi même ton interrogation. "A + article indéfini" est faux. Je vais "au" bar se dit car "au" = "à + le" c'est a dire à + article défini.

Comment: @Kimi, on ne peut pas édicter une règle en disant que l'on dit toujours "dans un bâtiment", ainsi : 
 on va à la banque /  dans la banque est faux

Je pense que la distinction se fait lorsque l'on distingue si l'on parle d'un lieu géographique (je vais à la plage, à la grotte Chauvet) ou si l'on précise ou l'on se trouve à l'intérieur du lieu (je vais dans la grotte)

Comment: On va au musée, à la boulangerie, à la piscine, au cinéma... Il n'y a aucune règle générale qui concerne les bâtiments.