# Using “en” to replace noun after preposition

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, en

The pronoun "en" can be used to replace a phrase "de ...", as in

> Il y a (beaucoup de/peu de/quelques) restaurants.
>
> Il y en a (beaucoup/peu/quelques-uns).

If the phrase is after the preposition, such as in

> Je suis allé **à** (beaucoup de/peu de/quelques) restaurants.

can we use *en* at all? Or do we always have to drop it?

> Il y a des centaines de restaurants dans la ville. J'**en** suis allé **à** (beaucoup/peu/quelques-uns), et ils sont assez bien, à mon avis.

or

> Il y a des centaines de restaurants dans la ville. Je suis allé **à** (beaucoup/peu/quelques-uns), et ils sont assez bien, à mon avis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ***en*** can have as antecedent *(beaucoup de/peu de/quelques)* + something, but the issue is with the intransitive verb ***être*** with which *en* cannot be used that way.

You need to select a transitive verb, for example *fréquenter*, *visiter*, *essayer* then ***en*** will be possible, e.g.:

> Il y a des centaines de restaurants dans la ville. J'**en** ai essayé quelques-uns, et ils sont assez bien, à mon avis.

Comment: Thanks. Can I still say "Je suis allé à (beaucoup/peu/quelques-uns)", without the **en**?

Comment: You might say: *Je suis allé **dans** beaucoup/peu **d'entre-eux***, *je suis allé **dans** quelques-uns (**d'entre-eux**)*

Comment: Thanks. Is there an explanation why we say "Je vais **dans un** restaurant", but "Je vais **au** restaurant"?

Comment: *Au* = *à le*, see also http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14734/aller-dans-un-bar-aller-%C3%A0-un-bar

Answer (score 2):

First, I wouldn't say "je suis allé **à** un restaurant, mais

> "je suis allé **dans** un restaurant."

ou

> "je suis allé **au** restaurant."

Now, to answer the question, if I had to use a pronoun I would take **y** when you are not replacing something that follows **de**.

> "j'y suis (beaucoup/peu/souvent) allé."

Comment: I think the meaning could be different. If I want to say "There are many restaurants in the city. I've been to some of them, and they are pretty good." I don't think the part "I've been to some of them" can be properly translated with your suggestions.

Comment: you are right : my suggestion would rather be used for "There are many restaurant in the city. I went there many time. "If you want to say: "I've been to some of them", I would say "je suis allé dans certains de ceux-ci."