# être dans/à + restaurant

Tags: expressions, prépositions

[This question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14734/aller-dans-un-bar-aller-%C3%A0-un-bar) discusses the preposition to use with the verb *aller* in combination with a place such as a bar or a restaurant.

Do the same rules apply when using the verb *être* instead? That is, if the question is

> Où es-tu ?

the answer can be

> Je suis au restaurant.
>
> Je suis dans un restaurant.
>
> Je suis à McDonald's.

but **not**

> Je suis dans le restaurant.
>
> Je suis à un restaurant.
>
> Je suis dans McDonald's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- L'expression correcte à retenir est: "**au restaurant**".
- Quand on emploie le "Je suis dans le restaurant", c'est pour un contexte bien précis. Par exemple, imaginons que mon ami a convenu d'un rendez-vous avec moi, et que nous devons nous rejoindre devant le Mac Do. L'heure convenue arrive, et il ne me voit toujours pas, il m'appelle sur mon portable pour me dire "Mais où es-tu donc? Je ne te vois pas!". Je lui réponds: *Je suis dans le restaurant*. Ici, je lui indique une localisation précise: je ne t'ai pas attendu dehors, je suis entré dans le restaurant. C'est la même logique pour "Je suis dans un restaurant". Ce n'est plus la même chose que l'expression "être/aller au restaurant".
- <strike>Je suis *à McDonald's*</strike> 
    <strike>Je suis *dans McDonald's*</strike> 
    <strike>*Je suis à un restaurant*</strike> 
   sont toutes incorrectes.

McDonald's est un nom de restaurant, on utilisera "à", ou "au" si le nom commence par "le". Ici c'est **le** McDonald's ou **le** McDo (plus courant), donc on dira au McDo (qu'on écrit souvent à la française de diverses manières, ex: Mac Do)

Mais attention, quand le nom du restaurant est un nom de personne, on fait comme s'il s'agissait d'une vraie personne. On n'utilisera pas "à/au".

- Je suis **chez** Léon.
  Si la personne ne sait pas que "Léon" est un restaurant, on dira pour lever l’ambiguïté:
- Je suis **au restaurant** "Léon".

Il peut bien sûr y avoir des exceptions, ce n'est pas une règle absolue.

Et bien que "McDo" soit en fait un nom propre si on y regarde bien, on le considère comme un nom commun, on ne dira pas "Je suis chez McDo", mais *au McDo*.

EDIT:

Pour répondre à une demande de précisions.

- On dit "Le Burger King", etc, ce sont des noms de marques précédées par "le". Donc "aller au Burger King".
- Quand il s'agit de marques moins connues, on pourra préciser par exemple, qu'il s'agit d'un restaurant. (Comme dans l'exemple de "Léon")

*Je vais au restaurant "Northville"*.
*Je vais au Northville.* (si la personne est capable de comprendre qu'il s'agit d'un restaurant)

Comment: Merci pour la réponse détaillée ! La plupart des noms de restaurants commencent-ils automatiquement aussi avec **le** ? Par exemple, "je suis au KFC", "je vais au Burger King's", "il va au Starbucks", "nous sommes au Northville Restaurant"  ?

Comment: Il paraît que je donne des réponses trop longues et détaillées... Je vais éditer ma question pour rajouter ces précisions, parce que je n'ai pas la place dans les commentaires (ça va me valoir des downvotes, mais tant pis, je trouve qu'on ne peut pas répondre correctement dans les commentaires quand il faut un peu développer)

Comment: "Nous sommes au "Northville Restaurant" = se dira tout à fait si le nom du restaurant est un bloc "Northville-Restaurant". Il est également possible que le nom soit simplifié et qu'on dise: "Nous sommes au restaurant Northville"/ "Nous sommes au Northville".

Comment: La reponse est probablement correcte mais je ne serai pas aussi categorique. Il est courant d'utiliser les autres prepositions a l'oral: par exemple, a Dijon, tout le monde va au Vieux Leon, et non "chez le Vieux Leon". A Auxerre, j'entends indifferement "on va a MacDo" ou "on va au MacDo

Comment: Ce n'est pas catégorique, j'ai écrit que: ce n'était "pas une règle absolue, il peut y avoir des exceptions" (en fait, c'est seulement une règle d'usage). Et là, dans cet exemple, ce n'est pas tout à  fait la même chose qu'un nom, ça revient ici à avoir un resto qui s'appelle "LE Léon". On ne dit pas "chez", en général en français, quand il y a un "LE" (sauf registre particulier), on dit chez+nom de personne, directement. Beaucoup de noms de restos peuvent contenir un nom, j'aurais peut-être dû préciser que c'était valable pour un prénom.