# Dit-on à ou dans quel restaurant êtes-vous?

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Dit-on: Vous êtes dans quel restaurant à Ottawa? ou Vous êtes à quel restaurant à Ottawa?

Comment: Duplicate ? [être dans/à + restaurant](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23665/358)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [être dans/à + restaurant](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23665/%c3%aatre-dans-%c3%a0-restaurant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles mais pour éviter la répétition des ***à***, je choisirais probablement ***dans***.

> Vous êtes ***dans*** quel restaurant à Ottawa?

Dans la réponse, quand on nomme le restaurant, c'est en revanche ***à la*** ou ***au***, parfois ***chez*** :

> On est ***à la*** Tour d'Argent à Paris.

> On est ***au*** Riviera à Ottawa.

> On est ***chez*** Delmo à Montréal.