# Différence entre "à la cuisine" et "dans la cuisine"

Tags: prépositions

Quelle est la différence entre les deux phrases: "Je vais dans la cuisine (ou dans le supermarché)" et "je vais à la cuisine (ou au supermarché)"? Merci de vos réponses!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aller dans un bar / Aller à un bar](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14734/aller-dans-un-bar-aller-%c3%a0-un-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour moi, on utilise aller à quand le lieu est un endroit à part entière, comme aller au cinéma, aller à la boulangerie. La cuisine n'est pas vraiment un lieu dans ce sens, c'est une pièce de la maison, donc j'utiliserais aller dans la cuisine. Par exemple, on dit "je vais dans ma chambre", pas "je vais à ma chambre". Mais ce qui est intéressant, c'est que par exemple, si on est à l'hotel, on a plutôt tendance à dire "je vais à la chambre", et ça, je ne sais pas vraiment l'expliquer!

Comment: Probablement l'usage, sans autre rime ni raison?

Comment: Oui probablement!

Comment: Que veut-dire "un lieu à part entière" ? "La cuisine n'est pas un lieu" Ah, bon, qu'est-ce que c'est alors ? Il y a en français une différence d'emploi entre *à* et *dans* un lieu.

Comment: J'aurais tendance à dire qu'en disant "dans la cuisine/salle de bain" on indique simplement qu'on va dans la pièce, alors qu'en disant "à la cuisine/salle de bain" on sous-entend "pour y faire quelque chose en rapport avec le lieu". C'est pour ça qu'on dit "je vais aux toilettes" et pas "dans les toilettes" en règle générale, sauf si par exemple "je vais dans les toilettes pour réparer la chasse d'eau". "Au cinéma" sous-entend pour voir un film, "dans le cinéma" indique simplement qu'on va dans le lieu, par exemple "il fait froid dehors, je vais (rentre) dans le cinéma pour attendre mon ami".

Comment: Cette explication de Simon est bien plus claire, je n'arrivais pas à articuler cette différence usuelle.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le contexte où l'expression est *aller à ...*:

> Je vais dans la cuisine

semble insister sur le fait que vous serez à l'intérieur de la cuisine, alors que:

> Je vais à la cuisine

ne semble pas insister sur cet aspect de la même façon. Je dirais qu'il faut une bonne raison pour utiliser *dans la cuisine*, et que *à la cuisine* est l'expression à utiliser par défaut.

Google ngrams sembler aller dans ce sens:

[image]

Comment: Tu y es presque quand tu dis que ça dépend de si on est à l’intérieur ou non, voir [ici](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dUEp7k6pEeEC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=%22aller+%C3%A0%22+%22aller+dans%22&source=bl&ots=E53jmuovaZ&sig=hUsw5WUged7FRvBfx4QQyl14jF8&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx6-3ZvsvSAhXINhoKHSLtDzQ4ChDoAQgyMAU#v=onepage&q=%22aller%20%C3%A0%22%20%22aller%20dans%22&f=false) pour rendre ta réponse plus claire.

Comment: @Laure - je vais regarder. Merci!